# Override Resource Values in Android Library Bound in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We have created a Xamarin binding for a 3rd party library Android library that we need to use in our Xamarin Android app, the library is in the form of an AAR.

Since the library presents UI it has an option for customising certain colours etc by redefining resource values within the app, for example:

```
<resources>
   <color name="ThirdParty_accent">#9200aa</color>
   <color name="ThirdParty_accentDark">#76008a</color>
   <color name="ThirdParty_accentLight">#be7cca</color>
</resources>
```

This mechanism doesn't seem to be working with the bound library, when we define these values within our app they don't override the defaults defined in the AAR.

Is this something that is supported within a Xamarin binding? Is there a particular technique we need to use?

Comment: I mean that the AAR already contains values for the colours, if you want to change them then you are supposed to re-define them in a resource file within the app. When we follow this process the values in the app are ignored and the values from the AAR continue to be used instead.

Comment: Did you defined the same resource names as them which in the .aar ?

Comment: Yes we used the same name.

Comment: This is weird. In native Android, gradle is compiled by default to look for the nearest dependency overlay.Maybe you could report it on [xamarin.android issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues).

Comment: Is this the issue not that once we've bound the library into a DLL then gradle isn't involved? I will report the issue on github.

Comment: I don't think gradle is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be caused by typos in the documentation for the resources we were needing to re-define.

It seems this does work through a Xamarin bound library.